# How to remove the following/trailing comma on the final value (javascript)?

Tags: javascript

As the title suggests I'm trying to remove the last "," that appears when i return my function relative to a specific inputted name: For example I'm getting the following returned: "cat,bird,tiger, " when I'm trying to return "cat,bird,tiger " i have tried string = string.replace(/,\s*$/, ""); but this replaces all commas.
here is my current code.

```
let string = "";

for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  console.log(result[i].animal)
  string = string + result[i].animal + ",";
}
if(string != ""){
console.log(string);
}
else{
  console.log("NOT FOUND");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map the array to the `animal` properties, then join by a comma instead:

```
const string = result.map(({ animal }) => animal).join(',');
```

To tweak your original code, add a comma to the *beginning* of the concatenated string if `string` is not empty:

```
let string = '';
for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  string += (string ? ',' : '') + result[i].animal;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, the tweaked code worked. As a beginner can you explain what the code in the parenthesis is doing exactly and give it some context on how that did what i was after?

Comment: It destructures the `animal` property from the object being iterated over and extracts only that value from every object, creating a new array. It's like `.map(r => r.animal)`. Then all you need to do is join the array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

i  use  this code for everywhere i want have like this string

```
 item,item,item,item,....,item
```

in first time i didn't add any comma and after then first add comma and then add item

```
if(string!=""){
        string+=","
      }
```

```js
let string = "";

for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  if(string!=""){
    string+=","
  }
  console.log(result[i].animal)
  string = string + result[i].animal ;
}
if(string != ""){
console.log(string);
}
else{
  console.log("NOT FOUND");
}
```